# Get command line when I run C++ program with SDL

Tags: c++, qt, sdl

I have a basic program to create a window with SDL and the only thing it gives me when I compile and run the program is a command line prompt that says `Press <RETURN> to close this window...` i am not sure what is causing this. Does someone know how to fix this?

here is the main.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window* window;

    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
                "Requiem",
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                640,
                480,
                SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN|SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
             );

    if(window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Could not create window: " << SDL_GetError() <<  std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Delay(3000);

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the .pro if needed

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

LIBS += -L C:/Users/Zach/Documents/dev/libs/SDL2-2.0.1/i686-w64-mingw32/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Users/Zach/Documents/dev/libs/SDL2-2.0.1/i686-w64-mingw32/include

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

and a picture of what I see

[image]

Comment: As I recall, SDL applications are not console applications.

Comment: @JoeZ when i created the project i just chose "Plain C++ Application" was I supposed to choose something else?

Comment: @JoeZ even when I add a `std::cout << "Blah blah";` it does not show even in the command line

Comment: Does anyone know anything i can try, I can not find out how to fix this and its very frustrating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the project settings, and go to the "run" tab, and then uncheck "Run in Terminal".

Then go in your .pro file and comment out "CONFIG += console".

Then go to Project > Clean All.

Then rebuild and run your project.

EDIT:

That will make it so that the `stdout` and the `stderror` gets redirected to the "Application Output" tab in Qt Creator.

The reason your `std::cout` didn't show up is probably because it didn't get flushed out.  You have to end a line for it to go out.

```
std::cout << "Some text" << std::endl;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you that helped a lot. I also realized that somehow the sdl2.dll got deleted out of the debug folder so I added it back and everything works now! Thanks again